# How I access the string from url in middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware

How I access the url parameter in my middleware

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^my_url/(?P<string>[\w\-]+)/$', my_view),
]
```

Now I want to access the string vale in my middleware. Here is my middle ware code

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Here I want a string variable value
```

Is there any solution to access the value of string variable

Comment: you can access and manage it from views so why specifically you want to access it in middleware?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL, along with all request data, is held in attributes of the request object.

Try [`request.path_info` or `request.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects)

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I would like to know how do I have access to the request attribute? Using a middleware, since I need it to get the subdomain and do some logic using this attribute.

Comment: You should have the request object in a middleware already. For everywhere else where you don't have the request object in scope, use django-threadlocals